# Series converges conditionally only if ratio test fails?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, conditional-convergence

It'd only just occurred to me that all conditionally convergent series must fail the ratio test - ie.

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n \,\,\,\text{conditionally converges}\implies{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|=1}\lor{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|\,\,\,\text{DNE}}$$

This surely must be a well-known consequence of the ratio test although I don't find it mentioned on Wikipedia/Wolfram. Is there a name for this result?

Or perhaps I've misinterpreted something incorrectly?

Comment: That is just using contraposition: $p\implies q$ gives you $\neg q\implies \neg p$. And then If the ratio test **doesn't** fail, then the series $\sum|a_i|$ is convergent. In particular, it is not conditionally convergent.